# Get unique values in a for loop (Spreadsheets)

Tags: for-loop, google-sheets-api

I'm currently trying to create a script that searches one sheet for rows that match a certain condition and then copies them to another sheet. This I can do. But I want to run it again and this time only get rows I didn't copy before and this is where it all fails because it keeps copying them again.

This is what I tried to do, but failed:

```js
var originSheet = somesheet;
var originArray = somesheet.getRange(somerange).getValues();
var finalSheet = someothersheet
  
      
    for (var j = 0; j < originSheet.getLastRow()-1;j++){
      
      
      if(originArray[j][9] == "Criteria"){
              
        for (var i = 1; i <= finalSheet.getLastRow(); i++){                
              
          var ID = finalSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
          
          
          if(originArray[i][0] !== ID){
            
            finalSheet.getRange(finalSheet.getLastRow()+1,1).setValue(originArray[j][0]);
            finalSheet.getRange(finalSheet.getLastRow() ,2).setValue(originArray[j][1]);
```